# Dúvida web.config

Tags: http, web.config

Preciso que não mostre o endereço físico real em um link para baixar um arquivo em meu site.

O link do arquivo quero que fique assim:
[UrlSite]/downloads/nome arquivo.extensão

E estou tentando utilizar o seguinte código no meu web.config:

```
<rule name="Downloads Redirecionar">
    <match ignoreCase="true" url="^downloads/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/public/arquivosDownload/{R:1}.{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Mas não está funcionando. Como se ele não utilizasse a regra. Quando clico para abrir em uma nova aba o link para download ele abre a pagina:

[http://[UrlSite]/Downloads/nome_arquivo.extensão](http://[UrlSite]/Downloads/nome_arquivo.extens%C3%A3o)

sem redirecionar para:

http://[UrlSite]/public/arquivosDownload/nome_arquivo.extensao

O que estou fazendo de errado que não está funcionando?

Comment: Isso realmente é possível? Você já viu algum post/tutorial explicando isso?

Comment: Então, pior que não sei se é. Apenas me disseram aqui onde trabalho que tenho que fazer este esquema acima. Esta foi a primeira coisa que se passou na minha cabeça, mas não sei se é o correto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez seja a falta de `stopProcessing`, também é necessário remover o `/` da frente de `/public`, deve ficar assim:

```xml
<rule name="Downloads Redirecionar" stopProcessing="true">
    <match ignoreCase="true" url="^downloads/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/arquivosDownload/{R:1}.{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Deu certo! Nossa mas que raiva, por causa de uma barra não ter dado certo. E fiz um monte de modificação sendo que era só isso. Mas obrigado por acompanhar guilherme

Comment: @RenanKaicLopes é porque o web.config já funciona como um "root" da pasta atual, claro que pode haver variações em sub-pastas, mas para o seu caso assim funciona ;)